# Getting html elements of another page with window.open()

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to access html elements from an html page I access with window.open().

These are my htmls:

firstpage.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function openPage() {
  return window.open("secondpage.html")
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

secondpage.html

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello!</h2>
<p>This is the second page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("firstpage.html")
html = browser.execute_script("return openPage().document;")
print html
```

What I'm expecting to get is a reference to the document element of the second page. This seems to work in the Firefox web console. When I test the script, the second page opens, but the first page seems to hang and after a while I get a dialog saying:

"A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete."

With the "Stop" and "Continue" buttons. Pressing "Continue" the dialog keeps to appear,  when I eventually press "Stop", the html python variable contains the same text of the dialog.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
As in the @e1che answer, this is the right way to do it:

firstpage.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function openPage() {
  window.open("secondpage.html", "secondpagewindow")
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("firstpage.html")
browser.execute_script("openPage()")
browser.switch_to_window("secondpagewindow")
print browser.page_source
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing well,

but you miss to switch your driver to the new window.

so right after you're `browser.execute_script("return openPage().document;")`

You write something like :

```
driver.switch_to_window("windowName")
```

I let you search [here for more infos and tricks](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html) ;)